# Не добавляет знак '+'(плюс) в базу

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго времени суток!

Возникла такая проблема, php не добавляет знак '+'(плюс) в базу. Никаких ошибок нет, знак просто обрезает. Команда стандартная:

```
mysql_query('INSERT INTO table (text) VALUE (myvar)');
```

Пробовал добавлять без предварительной фильтрации функцией `htmlspecialchars()` результат один и тот же. Подскажите как исправить эту проблему!

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql_query('INSERT INTO table (`text`) VALUE ('myvar')
```

Просто из-за того что вы не экранируете - происходит суммирование с пусто

Comment: А не подскажите, почему в update запросе тот же результат обрезания плюса, хотя здесь я экранировал переменные. Привожу подробный код:
$queryUpdatePost = mysql_query("UPDATE news SET cat='$cat',text='$text',title='$title' WHERE id='". $_POST['id'] ."'");

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, либо следует обрабатывать htmlspecialchars и экранировать или у Вас уже используется функция, которая при обработке удаляет все посторонние символы.